# Calculate disk peak size in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, bioinformatics

I need to benchmark tools in terms of their maximum(peak) disk use.We have observed that tool creates temporary files on disk.
So, I want to figure out how much peak disk space it utilizes (bytes written) for storing temporary files during its execution.

Comment: Do they all get stored in the same directory?

Comment: @hellyale : Yes they all get stored in same directory.

Answer (score 3):

The number of bytes written is not necessarily the peak in disk usage.

There are a number of ways to do this.

1) `df`  or `du` will give you the disk usage at that time. If you do a `df` every second, this might give you enough information. This is assuming that the process runs long enough to get multiple samples. If this works for you, it is probably the easiest way.

2) If you know which directories or files are used or created, you could enhance the previous way of using `df` or `du` by combining with `inotifywait` instead of sleeping a fixed interval:

```
while inotifywait -q -e modify filename >/dev/null; do
    df >> df-log-file
done
```

See `man inotify` for more options.

3) If you run the program in a VirtualBox, create a virtual disk that is dynamically allocated. The actual file for that VDI will grow when the room is needed. So the size of the VDI should be the start-size plus the peak-size of the temp-files. I have no idea how exact the result will be.

There should be many more ways of doing this.